# Get type of variable in annotation processor

Tags: java

I have annotation processor. I retrieve the list of variables of the class that was annotated with my annotation this way:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
        Set<? extends Element> annotatedElements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
        for (Element el : annotatedElements) {
            try {
                generate(el);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void generate(Element annotatedElement) throws IOException {
        TypeElement targetClass = (TypeElement) annotatedElement;
        List<? extends Element> enclosedElements = targetClass.getEnclosedElements();
        List<VariableElement> fields = new ArrayList<>(enclosedElements.size());
        for (Element field : enclosedElements) {
            if (field.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD && !field.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.STATIC)) {
                fields.add((VariableElement) field);
            }
        }
       processFields(fields);
}
```

Now `fields` List contains list of all variables. But i need to extract the TYPE of variables, so for example if class has
`private String blabla` i want to get`String`

I am doing it following way:

```
void processFields(List<VariableElement> elements){
    List<String> types =elements
    .stream()
    .map( e -> e.asType().toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());        
}
```

List `types` now contains all types of variables. However, if i have class like this

```
@MyAnnotation
public class Test{
  @NotBlank(message = "message")
  private String name;
}
```

The type of the variable `name` is not string, its
`(@javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank(message="message") :: java.lang.String`

How can i get just type without annotations then? Is there any way?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Add members and override `init()` to get the instances of
[Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html)
and
[Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html).

```java
...
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
import javax.lang.model.util.Types;
...
    /** See {@link javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment#getElementUtils()}. */
    protected Elements elements = null;
    /** See {@link javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment#getTypeUtils()}. */
    protected Types types = null;
...
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        elements = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
        types = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
    }
...
```

FYI, you can simplify your `generate(Element)` method:

```java
...
import javax.lang.model.util.ElementFilter;
...
private void generate(Element annotatedElement) throws IOException {
    List<VariableElement> fields =
        ElementFilter.fieldsIn(Collections.singleton(annotatedElement)).stream()
        .filter(t -> (! t.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.STATIC)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    processFields(fields);
}
```

Your `processFields(List<VariableElement>)` method could look something
like below.  I made all the steps explicit but you can look at
[TypeElement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html)
and
[Name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Name.html)
methods to determine which String you want.

```java
void processFields(List<VariableElement> in) {
    List<String> out =
        in.stream()
        .map(e -> e.asType())           /* javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror */
        .map(e -> types.asElement(e))   /* javax.lang.model.element.Element */
        .map(e -> (TypeElement) e)      /* javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement */
        .map(e -> e.getQualifiedName()) /* javax.lang.model.element.Name */
        .map(e -> e.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```